# Identify and resize newly opened external window

Tags: c++, windows

I've created a program to identify existing maximized windows and log their locations using EnumWindows and GetWindowPlacement.

Assuming I know the location of a desired EXE, I can open it just by calling the external process caller. But what is the best way to identify the newly opened window and set its location?  It's safe to assume that a program with the same name may already be open (two instances of cmd, for instance).

I believe once the window is identified I can set its location with [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is this the right question to be asking?  Is there a way to open a program and receive a HWND handle back instead?

In the Event Hook vein, I have this code:

```
HWINEVENTHOOK hook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, NULL, proc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT );

BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL, szPath, &saProcess, &saThread, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &piProcessC);

if (hook) {
    UnhookWinEvent(hook);
}
```

Which creates a hook and then creates a process (I'm opening up Notepad++).

The proc function it calls is:

```
void CALLBACK proc(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hWnd, LONG obj, LONG child, DWORD thr, DWORD time) {
    if (IsWindow(hWnd)){



        WINDOWPLACEMENT *wp = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        wp->length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);

        GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, wp);
        wp->rcNormalPosition.top = (long) 363;
        wp->rcNormalPosition.bottom = (long) 1021;
        wp->rcNormalPosition.left = (long) 1444;
        wp->rcNormalPosition.right = (long) 2551;


        BOOL tmp = SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, wp);
        cout << "FOUND IT\n";
    }

}
```

The proc function does not appear to get called, so is the hook not catching anything?

Oh, and I'm not sure the WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT is right, this is just a simple EXE doing the calling.

Comment: `SetWinEventHook` can catch windows being created/shown.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of googling, but I only partly understand Event Hooks.  I'm adding what I have to the original comment, but the hook doesn't appear to catch anything and the proc function doesn't seem to get called

Comment: I can't say I'm overly competent myself, but I've noticed some things like `EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW` better. To find out for sure, you can accept more and log which values happen.